# I need to insert <span> tags in all <td> and <th> tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML code as follows

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid">
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            Header 1
        </th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            Header 2
        </th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            Header 3
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            Row 1 -- Column 1
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            Row 1 -- Column 2
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            Row 1 -- Column 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 1
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 2   
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 3   
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Which will give this output
[image]

I want to have  tags inside all  and  tags without disturbing the current code.
I can only use JavaScript (strictly no jQuery) as it is a third party application which consumes the code and it needs span tags.

Could you please help me inject span tags so the output code would look something as follows

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid">
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            <span>
                Header 1
            </span>
        </th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            <span>
                Header 2
            </span>
        </th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            <span>
                Header 3    
            </span>             
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 1 -- Column 1
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 1 -- Column 2
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 1 -- Column 3
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 1
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 2   
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; text-align: center;">
            <span>
                Row 2 -- Column 3   
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

See the  and  tags are injected with span.
**I am Also not able to use querySelector**
Could someone please help me to inject span tags like this

Comment: So some `td`s have a `span` tag and some don't in the original markup?

Comment: @SerShubham yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this one

```
const ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for (th of ths) {
    if (!th.querySelector('span')) {
        th.innerHTML = '<span>' + th.innerHTML + '</span>';
    }
}

const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (td of tds) {
    if (!td.querySelector('span')) {
        td.innerHTML = '<span>' + td.innerHTML + '</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let _th = document.querySelectorAll("th"); 
let _td = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for(let i = 0; i < _th.length; i++) {
  let _thData = _th[i].innerHTML;
  _th[i].innerHTML = "<span>" + _thData + "</span>";
}

for(let i = 0; i < _td.length; i++) {
  let _tdData = _td[i].innerHTML;
  _td[i].innerHTML = "<span>" + _tdData + "</span>";
}
```